# If $y= |\sin x| + |\cos x|$, then $dy/dx$ at $x=2\pi/3$ is?

Tags: functions

If $$y= |\sin x| + |\cos x|,$$ 
then $dy/dx$ at $x = 2\pi/3$ is?

Ans: $(\sqrt{3} - 1)/2$

How can we differentiate modulus functions? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need to worry about the behaviour in the vicinity of $x=2 \pi /3$ where $\sin x $ is positive and $ \cos x $ is negative so
$$y=    \sin x - \cos x $$

$$y'=    \cos x + \sin x $$

$$y'(2 \pi /3)=    \cos (2 \pi /3) + \sin(2 \pi /3) = -\frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} =  \frac{\sqrt 3 -1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

In the second quadrant, $\sin x \geq 0, \cos x \leq 0$.

Remember that $z = |w|$ is $z=w$ for $w \geq 0$ and $z = -w$ for $w \leq 0$.

So the function you should be differentiating is $f(x) = \sin x - \cos x$. After the differentiation, evaluate the derivative at $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin \frac {2\pi}3=\frac {\sqrt 3}2, |\sin \frac {2\pi}3|=\frac {\sqrt 3}2$  As the functions are continuous, the sign will not change nearby.  Just evaluate each one at $x=\frac {2\pi}3$, decide whether the value is positive or negative near there, and resolve the absolute value bars appropriately.